# Graphics Intensive Application in Java

Tags: java, jogl, blending, particle-system

I'm making a particle engine in Java, and right now I'm using a subclass of `java.awt.canvas`. I'm using `canvas.getBufferStrategy().getDrawGraphics()` and then, when I'm done, using `canvas.getBufferStrategy().Show()`.

Now that I've got some particles (`graphics.fillOval(...)`) - I need to do some additive blending! Problem is, I can't find additive blending anywhere (googled). What I came up with from a google search is open gl through jogl. jogl would be a great move from graphics, since I have change the graphics color thousands of times a tick, and I can't find additive blending, but I'm just unsure as to whether or not jogl is standard and works on all (or most) computers.

Any thoughts or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to consider [`AlphaComposite`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html), as shown in this [kinetic model](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel).

Addendum: This [utility](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/composite) may be helpful in visualizing the effect of various compositing rules.

Comment: I would prefer JOGL if possible, and the requrements are java 2 and OpenGL. However, what if the user doesn't have OpenGL? That's why I'm looking at java 3d. If it has a software rendered as a fallback it would be perfect. Any thoughts?

Comment: When I've used JOGL, Java Web Start served the (myriad) decencies well enough. See also, [JOGL Demos](http://download.java.net/media/jogl/demos/www/).